# Parallel stream vs serial stream

Tags: java, lambda, parallel-processing, java-8, java-stream

Is it possible that a parallel stream could give a different result than a serial stream in Java 8? According to my information, a parallel stream is the same as a serial stream except divided into multiple substreams. It is a question of speed. All operations over the elements are done and the results of the substreams are combined at the end. In the end, the result of the operations should be the same for parallel and serial streams in my opinion. So my question is, is it possible that this code could give me a different result? And if it is possible, why does it happen?

```
int[] i = {1, 2, 5, 10, 9, 7, 25, 24, 26, 34, 21, 23, 23, 25, 27, 852, 654, 25, 58};
Double serial = Arrays.stream(i).filter(si -> {
    return si > 5;
}).mapToDouble(Double::new).map(NewClass::add).reduce(Math::atan2).getAsDouble();

Double parallel = Arrays.stream(i).filter(si -> {
    return si > 5;
}).parallel().mapToDouble(Double::new).map(NewClass::add).reduce(Math::atan2).getAsDouble();

System.out.println("serial: " + serial);
System.out.println("parallel: " + parallel);
```

---

```
public static double add(double i) {
    return i + 0.005;
}
```

and results are:

```
serial: 3.6971567726175894E-23

parallel: 0.779264049587662
```

Comment: Reducing using `atan2` makes no sense at all. It is not associative for example.

Comment: FYI: `si -> { return si > 5; }` should be just `si -> si > 5`, and you'd want to do the filter *after* the `parallel()`.

Comment: So the main problem is, that reduce is not associative function

Comment: No, the problem is that reduce *requires* an associative function

Comment: @Andreas, you may place `.parallel()` anywhere between stream start and terminal operation, the result will be the same.

Comment: The design and specification of the streams library is oriented around ensuring that (except in specially marked cases) the result is independent of sequential vs parallel execution.  (The "specially marked cases" are those where the stream itself has no meaningful encounter order, or operations explicitly ignore encounter order, such as findAny or forEach.)  The specification of the stream operations -- such as the requirement that the combiner function passed to reduce be associative, and more generally that behavioral parameters be stateless -- are there to support this property.

Comment: The call `.mapToDouble(Double::new)` is widening each `int` to `double`, boxing them into `Double` objects, just to unbox them afterwards to `double` value. If you want to convert `int` to `double`, a `.mapToDouble(i->i)` would be much more straightforward, skipping the object creation. But even simpler is [`.asDoubleStream()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#asDoubleStream--)… And, if you really need boxed values, use `Double::valueOf` instead of `Double::new`.

Comment: Or, well, just using `mapToDouble(NewClass::add)` would save you an entire step…

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The javadoc for [`reduce()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/DoubleStream.html#reduce-java.util.function.DoubleBinaryOperator-) says:

> Performs a reduction on the elements of this stream, using an **associative** accumulation function, [...] The accumulator function must be an **associative** function.

The word ["associative"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#Associativity) is linked to this java doc:

> An operator or function op is associative if the following holds:
>
> ```
>  (a op b) op c == a op (b op c)
> ```
>
> The importance of this to parallel evaluation can be seen if we expand this to four terms:
>
> ```
>  a op b op c op d == (a op b) op (c op d)
> ```
>
> So we can evaluate (a op b) in parallel with (c op d), and then invoke op on the results.
>
> Examples of associative operations include numeric addition, min, and max, and string concatenation.

As @PaulBoddington mentioned in a comment, `atan2` is not associative, and is therefore not valid for a reduction operation.

---

*Unrelated*

Your stream sequence is a bit off. You should filter *after* the parallel operation, the lambda can be shortened, and you shouldn't box the double:

```
double parallel = Arrays.stream(i)
                        .parallel()           // <-- before filter
                        .filter(si -> si > 5) // <-- shorter
                        .asDoubleStream()     // <-- not boxing
                        .reduce(Math::atan2)
                        .getAsDouble();
```

Comment: Unrelated part is completely unrelated. The `.parallel()` may be located in any place of your pipeline and the result will be the same.

Comment: @TagirValeev - Will it not run quicker if you parallel it earlier?

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare, no, it won't.

Answer (score 4):

When you use `reduce` with a parallel stream, the operations are not done in a specific order.

Therefore if you want parallel streams to produce a predictable result, your reduce operation must have the same answer no matter what order things are done in.

For example, reducing using addition makes sense, because addition is associative. It doesn't matter which of these you do, the answer is `6` in both cases.

```
(1 + 2) + 3
1 + (2 + 3)
```

`atan2` is not associative.

```
Math.atan2(Math.atan2(1, 2), 3) == 0.15333604941031637
```

whereas

```
Math.atan2(1, Math.atan2(2, 3)) == 1.0392451500584097
```

Answer (score 3):

Your reduce method produces different results, if the elements are given in a different orders.

So if you use a parallel stream the original order is not garanteed.

If you use a different reduction method (e.g. (x,y) -> x+y) it works just fine.

Comment: Order is always the same. The way the results are combined is different. Order-independent operation is commutative. Combination-independent operation is associative. Here order is kept, so the commutativity is unnecessary.

Comment: @TagirValeev, that only applies to ordered streams.

Comment: @the8472, surely unordered stream is unordered.

Comment: Yes, but in the absence of ordering serial and parallel streams may behave differently, which may not be relevant to OP's particular example but it does apply to the question in general.